# Issue with CTRL+D on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: c, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was working on an assignment using Windows Subsystem for Linux. Below is the C Code that was used to write a mini-shell for this assignment. 
I ran into an interesting issue using WSL. On line 35, you can see that I call the read function to read in the buffer and it does a check for null. When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, while using WSL, it will go into the if statement and prints the print message on line 36 infinitely and does not stop until I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit. When running this program on a Linux machine, it behaves appropriately and prints once, and brings us to the top of the loop.
Any ideas as to what this bug could be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types
#include <unistd.h>
#include <error.h>

char prompt[] = "$ ";

static int
Fork()
{
  pid_t pid;

  if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "fork error");
    return(pid);
}

int    
main(void)
{
  long MAX = sysconf(_SC_LINE_MAX);
  char buf[MAX];
  pid_t pid;
  int status, n;

  do {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, prompt, strlen(prompt));
    fflush(NULL);
    memset(buf, 0, MAX);
    if((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, MAX)) == 0) {
      printf("use exit to exit shell\n");
      continue;
    }
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0'; // chomp '\n'

    if (strncmp(buf, "exit", MAX) == 0) { // match
      break;
    }
    pid = Fork();
    if (pid == 0) {  // child
      execlp(buf, buf, (char *)NULL);
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "exec failure");
    }
    // parent
    if ((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0)
      error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "waitpid error");
  } while(1);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The program is in C but there are no options available to insert C Code snippets.

Comment: Your program tries to read past end-of-file. That doesn't strike me as a good idea. Apparently Windows agrees and just keeps returning end-of-file on the following reads.

Comment: OT: regarding: `buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0'; // chomp '\n'`  This is not a reliable method of removing a trailing newline.  A MUCH better method is: `buf[ strcspn( buf, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: OT: regarding: static int
Fork()
{`   It is a very poor programming practice to name functions the same a C library functions (even though the capitalization isn't exactly the same.)   This can be very confusing to the human reader

Comment: You likely expected read() interrupted by ctrl/D to return -1 instead of 0. This seems to be system-dependent behavior. I have a real Ubuntu which returns 0 as well.  Even if read() would return -1, following code is suspicious. What if strlen(buf) == 0? What then `buf[strlen(buf) -1]` will do?

Comment: WSL v2 (already available in preview) has a real Linux kernel, so all system calls should behave perfectly. Try that if in doubt.

Comment: For me, adding `tcflush(STDIN_FILENO, TCIFLUSH)` (i.e. discard data received but not read) before calling `read` solves the problem in WSL. `read` is expected to return 0 if Ctrl+D is typed at the start of a line of input, but I don't know whether it's specified what the terminal should do for a subsequent read. I did an strace on a Python session that uses GNU Readline and observed it sending `TCGETS` and `TCSETSW` IOCTLs before calling `read`, so I figured I'd try a simple flush, and it worked.

Comment: I think I've already told you this in another Q, but is the stdin of your program really a tty when running it in WSL? what would a `printf("%d\n", isatty(0))` at the beginning print? Control-D only has meaning when typed in a tty, it cannot be passed through a pipe; you can reproduce the same behavior on Linux by running your program as `cat | ./your_prog`.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of that `fflush(NULL)`. You should not mix buffered and unbuffered i/o.

Comment: @mosvy, yes, a console input file is a tty in WSL. A Linux shell environment would be broken beyond usefulness otherwise. Also, as I said in my previous comment, `tcflush(STDIN_FILENO, TCIFLUSH)` fixes the problem for me. I'm waiting for the OP and others to confirm that it works for them as well, and for someone more familiar with the specified behavior of Unix terminals to confirm whether this is allowed behavior in general, albeit unusual, or whether requiring a flush is an outright bug in WSL.

Comment: @eryksun there should be no need for `TCIFLUSH` -- that really looks like a bug in WSL. The ioctls issued by readline are a redherring -- readline is setting the tty in raw mode, it doesn't depend on the canonical/cooked mode of the tty driver to handle Control-D.

Comment: @mosvy, changing the mode with `TCSETSW` is clearly resetting something that makes it work. For example, in Python I can end a readline-based `input()` with an empty Ctrl+D. It raises the expected `EOFError`, and I can continue to read from stdin. But without readline it shows the same misbehavior. For example, a simple `while 1: sys.stdin.read(1)` is broken after entering Ctrl+D.

Comment: @eryksun as I told you, readline works completely different than the tty canonical mode (it interprets itself the ^D). A simpler testcase for this bug should be `sh -c 'while cat; do echo DONE; done'` -- that should print `DONE` each time you press ^D _at the beginning of the line_, and re-run the `cat`. How ^D/VEOF should work in canonical mode is specified [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09).

Comment: @mosvy, I'm not concerned about readline working in raw mode. That's unrelated to my point, which is only that after the mode gets reset by readline, I can use stdin normally again, e.g. `sys.stdin.read(1)` will work. So it's changing something in the console state that fixes the problem with `read()` subsequent to an empty Ctrl+D. Your test with the `cat` loop also demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @eryksun the standard spec link I gave you says " If ICANON is set, the EOF character shall be discarded when processed.". If WSL fails to do that, the EOF character would have to be discarded by hand with `TCIFLUSH`. Changing the tty mode back & forth with `TCSET*` may also cause that as a side-effect. But neither of these should be necessary (and it's not, on any Unix system).

Comment: @mosvy, great, I think that aptly describes what's happening here.

Comment: `read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, MAX)` can cause undefined behavior if it reads `MAX` bytes and doesn't leave the final `'\0'` terminating `char` value since later code assumes `buf` contains a properly-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

Different OSs use different keystrokes for EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on read() (Linux manpages v 3.54) does not specify that end of file (ctrl/D) causes read to return anything besides of 0. On the contrary, it says that return value zero indicates end of file. So you're relying upon undefined behavior. 
Somehow on your Linux ctrl/D causes error, thus read() returns -1. Your program in this case exits the loop. Or, ctrl/D is read literally, then read() returns 1.